# WordPress WooCommerce: How to allow only specified customers to pay by check?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I know that WooCommerce supports check payments by turning on the related setting (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/cheque/) but my question is: how can I enable this for only specific customers?

Basically, I want a way for the Admin to be able to pick which existing customers are allowed to pay by check. For all other customers, they should continue to pay with Credit Card.

Any advice on how to go about this is appreciated. Thank you for your time.